# GitHub слить файлы с определенного коммита - как?

Tags: git, github, git-checkout, tortoise-git

Есть репа на гитхабе с большим количеством файлов. Выкачивать все, чтобы взять от туда последние изменения, неудобно.

Нужно, чтобы можно было сливать изменения с определенного коммита.

Там такое есть вообще? Нужно не мне, а чтобы другие могли качнуть только обновления, так как люди не смогут выдирать правки самостоятельно.

Или можно как-то через tortoise git качнуть изменения с определенного коммита? Я бы уже сам выкачивал и выкладывал последние изменения.

Буду благодарен за помощь и советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для манипуляций с репозитарием нужна программа [git](http://git-scm.com/downloads)

Обновляем репозиторий до нужного комита.

```
git fetch
git checkout commit-hash
```

Получить список изменений от текущей версии до заданного комита:

```
git diff commit-hash
```

Изменения выдаются в виде патч файла.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.
А автоматом через tortoisegit не сделать?
У меня Git установлен, но в консоли я не работал совсем, по этому юзаю tortoisegit.

Comment: без понятия, я с tortoisegit не работал :)